# fetching multiple entities using HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Is it possible to fetch multiple entities using HQL? I find myself writing a lot of code like:

```
obj1 = HQL1;
if (obj1 == null)
  obj2 = HQL2;
```

So I am wondering if it is possible to fold the `obj1 == null` check into the HQL query and fetch obj2 at the same time in case the condition is true.

EDIT:

Consider code like this:

```
Animal cat, dog = null;
cat = currentSession.createQuery("from Cat where id = 1").uniqueResult();
if (cat == null)
  dog = currentSession.createQuery("from Dog where id = 2").uniqueResult();
```

My question is whether there is a way to write a single HQL query to fetch **both** `cat` and `dog` at the same time (but only fetch `dog` if `cat` is `null`, of course).

Comment: You have to give some more context here. You code hardly makes sense.

Comment: Even if you could, how would you assign it to `cat` or `dog`?

Comment: @acdcjunior: for instance make `uniqueResult` or whatever its equivalent return an array of entities.

Comment: You can return an array of `Object`. But you'd have to map it to the `cat`'s and `dog`'s properties manually.

Comment: I thought returning an array of `Object` is only possible by writing SQL queries instead of HQL ones?

Comment: Nope, that is not possible with only HQL like you want.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, your question really lacks context.  So its hard to answer.

You can perform a polymorphic query.  This is specific to Hibernate, not at all part of JPA.

```
List animals = session.createQuery( "from Animal" ).list()
```

this returns you all Animals, both Cats and Dogs.

From there you could construct a restriction as you need.  The problem with the type of restriction you seem to want is that it will likely require a subquery which can often lead to inefficient query plans on the DB server.